# Validation custom message (for the same form field) ignored

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii2

I'm using ActiveForm to generate my form. In the model, I have the following rules for the same field:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ['reviewMsg', 'required', 'message' => Yii::t('review', 'Review message cannot be blank.')],
        ['reviewMsg', 'string', 'max' => 255, 'message' => Yii::t('review', 'Review message should contain at most 255 characters.')],
        ];
    }
```

Now, client-side validation works fine, it reacts to the rules correctly. The custom message for breaking the `required` rule is shown as I specified it. However, the second custom message (text <= 255 characters) is being ignored, and instead a standard error message is shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [tooLong](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-stringvalidator.html#$tooLong-detail) property:

```
public function rules() {
return [
    ['reviewMsg', 'required', 'message' => Yii::t('review', 'Review message cannot be blank.')],
    ['reviewMsg', 'string', 'max' => 255, 'tooLong' => Yii::t('review', 'Review message should contain at most 255 characters.')],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Works! Out of curiosity: why does the standard `message` property fails in this case? I mean, it feels a bit inconsistent.

Comment: @lesssugar. Because `message` works only when value is not string. [See Detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-stringvalidator.html#$message-detail)